# How to wrap a function that returns void * in c

Tags: c, function-pointers

I am currently exploring a bit in the direction of function pointers in c, and I've mocked up a little example that I feel should work, but it instead produces a segmentation fault and I am not really sure why.

Here's the code I mocked up

```c
void *new_testarr()
{
    void *testarr = malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    return testarr;
}

void *test_wrap(void *(*functionpointer)(void))
{
    return (*functionpointer);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int *arr = (int *) test_wrap(new_testarr);

    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    arr[2] = 3;
    arr[3] = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

I tested the function new_testarr() by itself and there was no problem, but as soon as I try to wrap it then a segmentation fault occurs. I also tried adding an ampersand when passing the function in test_wrap(), but the same thing happened.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are missing `#include`. Add relevant `#include`. Are you getting compiler warnings?

Comment: `return (*functionpointer);` is taking a function pointer and returning it as a `void*`, which is not allowed. I think you meant to write `return (*functionpointer)();` - call the function through its pointer.

Comment: @KamilCuk , my apologies. I didn't bother adding it since its just stdlib and stdio

Comment: @RaymondChen , yes it does. I responded to your answer. Unfortunately I have to wait a few minutes before I can give you the green tick. Thank you very much for the response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return (*functionpointer);` is taking a function pointer and returning it as a `void*`, which is not allowed. I think you meant to write `return (*functionpointer)();` - call the function through its pointer.

Comment: why is it not allowed?

Comment: Y'know this makes a lot of sense. I guess my brain tripped because I didn't have any arguments to pass. Thank you very much for the response!

Comment: @TheFool function pointers cannot be converted to object pointers and back, in Standard C.  Implementations might allow it as an extension but an explicit cast is required (and the code should give a diagnostic message if no cast is used)

Comment: note, `return functionpointer();` works too, the `*` is superfluous

Comment: how are do you know if you got a function pointer or an object pointer?

Comment: @M.M , oh thanks for the info. I'll make a note of it

Comment: @TheFool Whether something is a function pointer or object pointer is encoded in its type.